# How to call a function in javascript on a key

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

 DatePickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend
 dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
 today: currentDate
 currentDate: ->
   today =  Date()
   today
```

`export default DatePickerComponent`

Reference Error, currentDate not defined. Also get it when 
    `today: currentDate`

How do I call this ?

I my handlebar file I want to access todays date.

Comment: `today: this.currentDate`

Comment: I get an error saying this is not defined in the top level

Comment: @sbatson5 that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest going back and boning up on the Ember object model and computed properties. What templates can display are properties. You want

```
currentDate: function() {
  return Date();
}.property()
```

or its equivalent CS.

Then in your template

```
Today is {{currentDate}}.
```

When you say

```
today: currentDate
```

You are setting the value of the `today` property to a local variable named `currentDate`, not to the object property named `currentDate`. There is no local variable named `currentDate`. Hence the `ReferenceError`. If you want to set a property equal to the value of another property (although that doesn't seem to be necessary here), you could do:

```
today: function() {
  return this.get('currentDate');
}.property('currentDate')
```

or more simply

```
today: Ember.computed.alias('currentDate')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is exactly what I was looking for.